# Browser or Apache2 does not see files: "server software is running but no content has been added"

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-13.10

after opening http 127.0.0.1 in the browser it displays info:

> It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server
>   software is running but no content has been added, yet.

**The point is I have added files to the DocumentRoot catalog**

Things i changed:

/etc/apache2/envvars

from

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

to

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=chiny 
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=chiny
```

file  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/chiny/Pulpit/lab


<Directory /home/chiny/Pulpit/lab/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com



    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

my DocumentRoot where i have my html files

```
root@chiny-HP-Compaq-dc7100-CMT-DX438AV:/home/chiny/Pulpit/lab# ls -l /home/chiny/Pulpit/lab 
razem 60 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 3096 sty 18  2013 10.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2562 sty 18  2013 11.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 3010 sty 18  2013 12.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 3045 sty 18  2013 1.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 3016 sty 18  2013 2.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2772 sty 18  2013 3.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2814 sty 18  2013 4.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2638 sty 18  2013 5.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2794 sty 18  2013 6.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2722 sty 18  2013 7.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2591 sty 18  2013 8.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 2620 sty 18  2013 9.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 chiny chiny  177 sty 18 18:37 index.html 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny    0 sty 18 14:43 plik 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 1711 sty 17  2013 styles.css 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiny chiny 3181 sty 17  2013 w3schoolslogo.gif
```

also /home/chiny/Pulpit/lab is owned and group by chiny

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 chiny chiny  4096 sty 18 18:37 lab
```

nothing changed in apache2.conf

**after restarting apache this info:**

```
root@chiny-HP-Compaq-dc7100-CMT-DX438AV:/home/chiny/Pulpit# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                             AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for chiny-HP-Compaq-dc7100-CMT-DX438AV 
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appeared that index.html was a orginal file from var/www that i copied to my documentroot. and content of this file is exactly this message:"It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."